Use javascript to test all URLs on a page for broken links
Please note that I have limited knowledge of Javascript and programming in general.
I contribute to a forum which allows you to customize your thread with HTML/CSS/JS.
On the thread page, the name of anyone who contributes to the thread is hyperlinked to take you to their profile page. If they have not created a profile page, the link leads to a variation of a 404 page not found page which just has the text "Oops! - The profile you requested is not ready". If they have created a profile page, it loads their profile page.
Is there a way to use javascript in order to test all the profile hyperlinks (so loop through the page on page load) and style them differently? My intention is to make the text blue if there is a profile page, and red if there isn't one.
In case it is useful, the hyperlink structure for the profiles looks like this (no ID or Class available):
<a href="https://subdomain1-userA.domain.com/">UserA</a>
<a href="https://subdomain2-userB.domain.com/">UserB</a>


Does this answer your question? detect 404 error on page load

There are a couple of ways you can approach to this, but basically you can use the fetch API to send a request to each URL and check the response.
Note that due to the Same-Origin Policy and CORS, this might not work if the profile pages are on a different domain and they don’t allow cross-origin requests.

If the broken link returns a 404 status you can use this:
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        fetch(link.href)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 404) {
                    link.style.color = 'red';
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }
};

This script will run when the page loads, find all the <a> elements on the page, and send a request to the URL specified in their href attribute. If the response status is 404, it will change the link color to red.

If the broken link redirects the user to another page:
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        fetch(link.href)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.url !== link.href) {
                    link.style.color = 'red';
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }
};

Same as before, but it compares the final URL of the response with the original URL of the request. If they are different, it means a redirect occurred.

Last, if no better alternative comes up, you can fetch the page content and check if it contains the specific text “Oops! - The profile you requested is not ready”:
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        fetch(link.href)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(body => {
                if (body.includes("Oops! - The profile you requested is not ready")) {
                    link.style.color = 'red';
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }
};

Please note that approach will greatly slow down your page load time.
